# OpenGLをC言語で扱ったファイルがコンパイルできません。

Tags: c, opengl

謎のエラーが出てきました。GlutMainLoopのところで毎回発生します。こちらの解決策を教えてもらえますでしょうか？

```
y);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
opengltest.c:11:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glutMainLoop' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   11 |  glutMainLoop();
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4gTgeX.o:opengltest.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `glutInit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4gTgeX.o:opengltest.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4gTgeX.o:opengltest.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4gTgeX.o:opengltest.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

ソースコードはこちらです。

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(void);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutCreateWindow("hoge");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display(){
    //PASS!
}
```

Comment: 解決はしていませんが、こちらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Undefined reference with GLUT for MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60705974/9014308) 他にはこんな記事も。[GLUTによる「手抜き」OpenGL入門](https://tokoik.github.io/opengl/libglut.html), [OpenGLとGLUTを使ってGCCでコンパイルする方法（Windows）](https://memoteki.net/archives/727), [Cのコンパイル(OpenGL)(MinGW)](https://qiita.com/muraki_111/items/6ddf7f12e48289848a86)

Comment: 解決した場合には役に立った回答にプラス投票/承認するか、自身で解決に至った情報を回答として投稿してください。 [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) 回答が付いた後に質問を大幅に書き換える(コードを削除する)のは **良くない編集** です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問のコードには

> ```
> #include <GL/glut.h>
> ```

とありますが、これは [GLUT - The OpenGL Utility Toolkit](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) と思われます。リンク先には

> We direct you to use FreeGLUT found on SourceForge: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/. The original GLUT has been unsupported for 20 years.

とかなり投げやりな記述しかされていません。より詳しく調べますとGLUTの最終版である3.7は 1998/05/07にリリースされていますが、対応OSはWindows 95とNTまでとなっています。それ以降はメンテナンスされていません。

この時点でとてもお勧めできるライブラリではありません。もちろんリンクが提示されているように互換ライブラリを使うのも一つの手ですが、その場合はまず質問者さんご自身が「24年前に既にサポートが終了してしまっているGLUTの、さらに互換ライブラリを使用する」と認識することが大前提です。間違っても「OpenGLをC言語で扱ったファイル」という認識ではいけません。

ところで、本来であれば `#include <GL/glut.h>` でエラーになったのではないでしょうか？ なんらか対処を行ったのであれば、そのことが説明されなければ第三者には対応方法がわからないことは理解されていますか？

---

それとは別に、エラーメッセージからWindows上でMinGW32を使用されているようですが、Windowsにおける標準のコンパイラーはVisual C++となります。
他のコンパイラーを使用される場合は、当然ながら標準コンパイラーとの差異を認識した上で利用する必要があります。そうであれば、質問文に使用しているコンパイラーが明記されるべきです。

Answer (score 1):

QiitaなどでFreeGlutの記事を見たりして解決しました。

原因として、FreeGlutのincludeだけ入れてしまっていた。

対策として、libフォルダの中身もちゃんと入れたらコンパイルされました。

---

- 次に質問する際は情報をもっと明確にする
- 質問を投げる前に自分で調べてみる

を徹底し、調べてみて情報が全く出てこないといった場合に質問させていただこうと思います。

「投票するには少なくとも15 信用度が必要となります」と表示されプラス投票ができませんでしたが、回答していただいた方、大変ありがとうございました。